# Data Factory Time Zone New Zealand Standard Time invalid

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to add an additional column to my pipeline for current date/time - why does Data Factory not like this?

```
@convertTimeZone(utcNow(), 'UTC', 'New Zealand Standard Time', 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss')
```

The error I get is

```
The parameters and expression cannot be resolved for schema operations. Error Message: { 
"message": "ErrorCode=InvalidTemplate, ErrorMessage=In the function 'convertTimeZone', the 
value provided for the time zone id 'New Zealand Standard Time' was not valid. "}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting development, using the ISO code NZ works without error - despite documentation saying it needs to be the name of the timezone.

```
@convertTimeZone(utcNow(), 'UTC', 'NZ', 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot using convert, you can using addHours .. in my country Indonesia is gmt +7 so Im using addHours(utcNow(), 7)

If you in new zealand you can change from 7 to 13